# GCP Postgres connections consumed when stressing spring boot service (using SQL Cloud proxy)

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, hikaricp

I'm working on a Spring Boot service to post data and persist it in a `GCP SQL Postgres` database. **The problem is when I stress the service with requests, I get an SQL exception about consuming all available connections**:

```
"FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections"
```

I figured out the issue and I added a proper hikari configuration to limit used connections and set a limit for when to close idle connections, here is my properties.yml configuration:

```
 type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
 hikari:
   initializationFailTimeout: 30000
   idle-timeout: 30000
   minimum-idle: 5
   maximum-pool-size: 15
   connection-timeout: 20000
   max-lifetime: 1000
```

The service works fine with this setup when I run it locally with the same database, **but it consumes all available connections when I run it from my cloud setup, and then get the same exception**.

**IMPORTANT!** I'm using SQL cloud proxy to connect to the database.

Here are screenshots for the database available connections:

1- before running the service

[image]

2- after running the service locally

[image]

3- after running the service from the cloud
[image]

Comment: Either you have multiple instances of your service connecting or you are re-creating the datasource (or whole application) while you need it. Generally these kind of errors come from the latter, but as a cloud environment is involved you might have auto-scaling things come into play.

Comment: @M.Deinum It's 1 instance without replicas, but I started to scope the issue within the SQL Proxy connection (at least that's my guess after some fix-and-try attempts). Would it be that SQL Proxy would mess up hikari's configuration?

Comment: I have used the Cloud SQL proxy and I've never faced this type of issues. If you try to connect Cloud SQL without using the Proxy, do you get the same error?

Comment: If anyone is using spring boot, seriously consider turning off open session in view, spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
I noticed performance problems with it enabled (which is the default in spring boot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few days of investigating this problem, we found a solution that is mitigating the problem but not solving it completely (the ideal solution is mentioned in the end).

If you want to keep using SQL Cloud proxy, then you need to accept the fact that you don't have full control over your database connections configuration, as SQL cloud proxy might keep those connections alive for more than you've configured it ([source](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/issues/147)).

**To mitigate this problem**, we used SQL Cloud proxy 1.19.2 from the [docker registry](https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/cloudsql-docker/US/gce-proxy?gcrImageListsize=30), and we used this hikari configuration:

```
hikari:
  idle-timeout: 30000 # maximum amount of time (in milliseconds) that a connection is allowed to sit idle in the pool
  minimum-idle: 1 # minimum number of idle connections that HikariCP tries to maintain in the pool, including both idle and in-use connections. If the idle connections dip below this value, HikariCP will make a best effort to restore them quickly and efficiently
  maximum-pool-size: 15 # maximum size that the pool is allowed to reach, including both idle and in-use connections. Basically this value will determine the maximum number of actual connections to the database backend
  connection-timeout: 20000 #maximum number of milliseconds that a client will wait for a connection
  max-lifetime: 20000 # maximum lifetime in milliseconds of a connection in the pool after it is closed.
```

The proper solution in this case, is to use a **Shared VPC** to have a private connection to your database where you will rely on your database driver to make those connections.